# Exporting each html classes to pdf file

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am trying to export html `.class` to merged pdf pages. Using this library: [pdfMake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/)

inside body there are two `.content` and I gave a4 styling..

```
.content {
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 842px;
}
```

and trying to export those elements to PDF.

### UPDATED

```
function makePdf(){
    pages = document.querySelectorAll(".content")
    html2canvas(pages, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500
                }]
            };


            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("document.pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

But the problem here. I can't export `.content` as a merged pdf pages. When I use it like this: `html2canvas(pages, {` it's export 2 merged pages but empty.

I tried to check it like this. `html2canvas(pages[0], {` then it's exporting one pdf file without a problem. but the second `.content` is not coming(of course...)

So I put it in `forEach` loop like below.

```
function makePdf(){
    pages = document.querySelectorAll(".content")
    pages.forEach(page => {
        html2canvas(page, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 500
                    }]
                };


                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("table.pdf");
            }
        });
    })

}
```

But then it's exporting `.content` pdfs one by one. it's not merged...

I am a bit confused. How can I achieve merged pdf pages from `.content`

Comment: did you tried by this way, which is given in document 
https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html

Comment: acually, I did, which is like this. `pdf.html(document.querySelector(".content"), {
   callback: function (pdf) {
    pdf.addPage()
      pdf.save();
   }
  });` but the problem is same. it's exporting empty pages @bajran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it nearly killed me but, in the end I solved the problem. used `jsPDF` library, instead of `pdfMake`.

**styles**

```
.content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**script**

```
function makePdf(){

    pages = document.querySelectorAll(".content")
    let count = 0;
    pages.forEach(page => {
        html2canvas(page, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                // var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var imgWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                pdf.addImage(data, 'PNG', '', '', imgWidth, 0);
                pdf.addPage(page)
                count++;
                if (count === pages.length) {
                    pdf.save("document.pdf")                        
                }
            }
        });
    }) //loop       
} //fn.
```

P.S: about the pdf page sizing, you should avoid using `internal.pageSize.getHeight();` if you expect good resolution. just give it 0

Answer (score 0):

```
async function makePdf(){
    const pdf = new jsPDF("a4");
    let documents = document.querySelectorAll(".content")
    html2canvas(documents).then(canvas => {
      var imgWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      var imgHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
      pdf.save("test.pdf"); // Generated PDF
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, there is an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: html2canvas(...).then is not a function`

Comment: @Tay please try with adding this line `const html2canvas = require("html2canvas");`

Comment: I am using the script tag cdn `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js` I guess doesn't need a require for that?

Comment: are you using plain java-script or agnularjs?

Comment: I am using plain javascript.

Comment: change   pdf.addPage(pages); to  pdf.addPage(pages[0]);  pdf.addPage(pages[1]);

Comment: I updated the question, could you please check it out?